# Is t-test for coefficients of linear regression two tailed?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test

What is the type of t-test used in the significance testing of coefficients/weights of linear regression? Is it one tailed or two tailed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does depend on the hypotesis you want to test. I mean you get the t-statistic in all statistical programs and you know your degrees of freedom, so fell free to calculate is the way you want.

If you mean some kind of 'standard ouput' i assume, that the p-values will in most cases be calculated two-tailed.